# xrl/nprobe install - command not found

Tags: command

I try to install xrl/nprobe when it is going to install first need to configure with ./configure but in my terminal give "bash: ./configure: No such file or directory" i work with ubuntu 12.04. if you can someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to install via apt-get without the source code?

See: 
http://www.nmon.net/apt/